# django authentication from two different apps (student, instructor)

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-1.7

In my site I have two type of user: student and instructor.
I want login with student or instructor.

I'm using [*AbstractBaseUser*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractBaseUser) to costumize the users (both)

But the [*AUTH_USER_MODEL*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model), allows only one user.

What is the best way to do this?

Ps.: I'm using django 1.7.7, python 3.4

Answer (score 0):

Create a CustomUser or BaseUser class in a different app (maybe call it  customauth) which will be used for authentication and be given to AUTH_USER_MODEL. All the authentication related and base user stuff can go to this app. Now if i understand correctly, the two apps for students and instructors can then have their entity class extended from the CustomUser class.And the maybe use [InheritenceManager](http://django-model-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/managers.html) depending on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Only work with (CustomUser or BaseUser)? Or I can use AbstractBaseUser? If I use your logical I'll be able to use the app in admin.py?